# Sass CSS :after background image not appearing

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to render a png icon on top of a button. The :after element is in the rendered html but the size is 0x0 and the icon doesn't appear. `my-button` is a generic web component that renders a button

```css
.grouped-buttons {
    button {
      margin: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      height: 28px; 
      width: 50px; 
      border: 1px solid rgba(193,203,214,0.8);  
      background: linear-gradient(#fff, #f2f6fa)
    }
  
    :first-child button {
      border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
      border-right: none;

      &:after {
        content: "";
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAL1JREFUWAntlzEOxSAMQz9fPR0H5nrtxGLJwnGHZnCXimDS6MUqMH7iM+e8RakkW2sNRfhXRF9qUuBb+pebQPXQzu96OC3eBN13e4LD9YZLpLquPcEUWG0p6ul+iN6s/vfwQzhW86fFSK46bk/Q3otPHjrNqyTbE0yBaiuZLgQZGTUegioppgtBRkaNh6BKiulCkJFR4yGokmI6+zx4uqOc5llBGE+LkUh13J6g7EG8Y1RJuPr2BFOg29q97gF+mSBWRkZEXAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
      }
    }
   }
```

```html
  <div class="grouped-buttons">
    <my-button >
      <button > </button> 
    </my-button>
    <my-button > 
      <button > </button>
    </my-button>
    <my-button > 
      <button > </button>
    </my-button>
  </div>
```

Comment: instead of auto use 100% and make it inline-block

Answer (score 0):

You have to set some sort of width, height, and display rules to tell the browser how to render the element. I went with a 20x20px block element, centered with `margin: 0 auto;` and set the image size using `background-size: contain;`. I rewrote your scss as css and removed the my-button tags to get it to work in the snippet but those things should be fine in your environment.

```css
.grouped-buttons button {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 28px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(193, 203, 214, 0.8);
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #f2f6fa)
  font-size: 0;
}

.grouped-buttons button:first-child {
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
  border-right: none;
}

.grouped-buttons button:first-child:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAL1JREFUWAntlzEOxSAMQz9fPR0H5nrtxGLJwnGHZnCXimDS6MUqMH7iM+e8RakkW2sNRfhXRF9qUuBb+pebQPXQzu96OC3eBN13e4LD9YZLpLquPcEUWG0p6ul+iN6s/vfwQzhW86fFSK46bk/Q3otPHjrNqyTbE0yBaiuZLgQZGTUegioppgtBRkaNh6BKiulCkJFR4yGokmI6+zx4uqOc5llBGE+LkUh13J6g7EG8Y1RJuPr2BFOg29q97gF+mSBWRkZEXAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="grouped-buttons">
  <button> </button>
  <button> </button>
  <button> </button>
</div>
```